# How can I add tags to an RDS cluster

Tags: rds, amazon-rds

There's a difference between an individual RDS instance and an RDS cluster, I can tag the RDS instance just fine via the AWS UI but can't seem to be able to tag the cluster.

How do you go about tagging an AWS RDS cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this isn't possible in the AWS Console. You have to use the API:

List tags:

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name arn:aws:rds:<region>:<account>:cluster:<cluster_name>
```

Add keys:

```
aws rds add-tags-to-resource --resource-name arn:aws:rds:<region>:<account>:cluster:<cluster_name> --tags '
[
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "MyCluster"
    },
    {
        "Key": "Environment",
        "Value": "dev"
    }
]'
```